# Still need to use <UL> tag for navigation and list of links?

Tags: html, list, navigation, html-lists

So I've heard many times that anytime you have a list of anything you should use a UL tag to list them instead of just a bunch of div's. But today I've been looking at how some sites have created their site and I am noticing some of the larger sites are not using the UL tag but instead a bunch of div's.

My question is, is it still better to use UL, or is there no difference between that and using a bunch of div's.

To illustrate what I'm talking about, which is better:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
<ul>
```

or

```
<div>Link 1</div>
<div>Link 2</div>
```

I noticed that even the Microsoft Windows page is using div's now. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/home

Thank you!

Comment: “Which is better” is a non-constructive question especially when no criteria have been specified. It’s almost like “Which one do you like?”

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Maybe that's because I don't know the reasons why one would be better or not, hence why I'm asking. Not sure how else I could have asked this without already knowing the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much your choice. Here is a very good article about the pros and cons of both techniques: 
http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

I guess if you are concerned about text-only browsers and accessibility, list are still better.. But not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a 6 vs. half dozen issue, but I'll take a crack at it. In my experience its best to use the `<ul>` set up because its a little faster and cleaner if you have a lot of links in your navigation. I would guess its a bit easier to set up "nested" or "sub-navs" as well.

as in

```
<ul>
    <li>link 1
        <ul>
            <li>link 1 a</li>
            <li>link 1 b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link 2</li>
</ul>
```

Of course you could do it either way, but I prefer this way, mostly for readability.

Answer (score 1):

In short, There's no difference at all.

Most people just prefer to use  &

because its easier to group together.